# Using sum in having clause

Tags: t-sql, sum

I have a simple query

```
select id,
(select sum(totalin) from xorderextra where xorderextra.id = xoi.id) as totalin,
from xorderinfo xoi
group by xoi.id
having (select sum(totalin) from xorderextra where xorderextra.id = xoi.id) > 1000
```

Now I would like to know is there a better way to replace sum filter in having statement. Is this a proper way to setup things, would this hurt a query, ie. would it have to sum numbers twice?

**New case **

```
select xoi.id,
       sum(xex.totalin) as totalin,
       sum(xooc.totalout) as totalout,
from xorderinfo xoi
inner join xorderextra xex on xex.id = xoi.id
inner join xorderout xoo on xoo.rid = xoi.id
inner join xorderoutcalc xooc on xooc.obracunid = xoo.obracunid
group by xoi.id
having sum(xex.totalin) > 1000
```

This is returning wrong results, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You may do a join and will improve performance dramatically!

```
select id,
       sum(xex.totalin) as totalin,
from xorderinfo xoi
inner join xorderextra xex on xorderextra.id = xoi.id
group by xoi.id
having sum(xex.xorderextra) > 1000
```

Comment: what if i would use multiple sums (from different table) in the same query? I believe using join would not return correct sum!

Comment: It deppends, if you want all to group by the same column, why wouldn't it work?

Comment: Not really sure, but I believe by joining multiple tables, you are getting duplicate rows. I tried query added above, and I get incorrect sums.

Comment: With inner join you might be limiting the results.. If you limit the number of rows that happear, the sum might change. You might want to use `left outer join` instead of `inner join`. Try it that way!

Comment: Actually left outer join should not be a problem. The problem is if we join a table with multiple rows, xorderoutcalc on xorderout. That is where we get duplicate rows and false sum. How to prevent this from happenning?

Comment: If the rows are equal, you can use distinct. Otherwise, make a subquery with id and totalin and make the join afterwards. But why do you want to make those joins if you don't get any information from them?

Comment: I have updated new case, but don't understand your suggestion " make a subquery with id and totalin and make the join afterwards". Would that be my original solution?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11265/discussion-between-af-and-john)

Comment: Make the select without the group by and see what would be the result sum (of one id), if it's not what you want, you need to make the select gives the result that you want. Maybe using `distinct`. Otherwise, use subqueries like stated in the question.

Comment: And one other thing, you should update your question and not my answer if you have more info :P

Answer (score 1):

You could rewrite it using a cte and [`SUM OVER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx):

```
WITH cte AS(
    SELECT id
    ,      SUM(xoi.totalin) OVER (PARTITION BY xoi.id) As TotalIn
    FROM xorderinfo xoi
)
SELECT cte.* FROM cte
WHERE TotalIn > 1000
```

Comment: @John: I'd expect it to be the fastest(assuming appropriate indexes).